# Access PostGIS on Heroku instance from GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, pgadmin-4, heroku

In Heroku, I have a PostgreSQL DB with all the credential to be accessed by outside (Host, Port, Database name, User, Password, URI). Then I connected pgAdmin with this database using the above credentials. Finally, I created a PostGIS extension for this database and I added a .shp file through the PostGIS Import/Export tool.

Now, I am trying to access this database as GeoServer Vector Data Source. When I enter all the db parameters (e.g Host, port and so on) in the "**Connection Parameters**" section I get an error:

```
Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "130.233.84.159", user "myuser", database "dbname", SSL off)
```

How can I solve this issue? Any hints?

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host

Comment: it doesn't work because actually I don't have the access to the pg_hba.config used by heroku postgresql...I mean: if I modify the one on my Pc of course nothing will happen

Comment: Do you have a proxy on your network?